# CLLocation speed return -1.0

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have problem. My GPS (on iPad mini 2 in Wifi and on iPhone 6 in 3G/4G) the speed return -1.0. Have an idea? 
This what i receive in console log:

Long: 12.5245, Lat: 41.9456, Speed:-1.0, kph: -3.6

Here the code in *didUpdateLocations()*

```
    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]
    var speed: CLLocationSpeed = CLLocationSpeed()
    speed = (locationManager.location?.speed)!

    SpeedLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f km/h", speed * 3.6)
    let long = String(Float(userLocation.coordinate.longitude))
    let lat = String(Float(userLocation.coordinate.latitude))


    print("Long: \(long), Lat: \(lat), Speed:\(speed), kph: \(speed * 3.6) ")
```

Comment: As the `CLLocation` [docs say](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/speed), "A negative value indicates an invalid speed." It just means that it couldn't calculate the speed. Perhaps this was the first location it received, so it didn't have anything to compare it against. Perhaps the distance covered was less than the `horizontalAccuracy` and therefore it's not confident calculating the speed. It could be tons of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem too. A negative value means an invalid speed. 
This is most of the time occured when you're inside a building and your location is moving a lot due to the building.

A simple fix would be:

```
if speed < 0 { 
    speed = 0 
}
```

This checks if the speed is negative. If it is, it'll reset it to 0.

Comment: If you're going to force `speed` to zero, I'd suggest `if speed < 0 { speed = 0 }`. While it appears that it's generally `-1`, I wouldn't code for that particular value. The rule is that "if negative, there is no speed".